# Groovy assert continue on failure

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I am using groovy scripts in my unit test. I have the following code snippet, and I'm using multiple asserts in my single test script.

```
def a ='welcome'
def b ='test'
def c ='welcome'

assert a==b
assert a==c
```

The first assertion was failed and execution was stopped. But I want to continue the further snippet of code.

similar to soft assert in selenium how should I collect all the failure exception in groovy.

Comment: "The first assertion was failed and execution was stopped. But I want to continue the further snippet of code." - What is it that you would like to happen when the first assertion fails?  Normally an assertion is used to express specifically that you do not want control to continue if it fails.  If you just want to check if a condition is true, use `if` instead of `assert`.

Answer (score 2):

In Groovy and Java, AssertionErrors are errors which the program can't recover from.  I would recommend setting up your unit tests to test/assert one thing per test.  This is a best practice for unit tests and it makes it much easier to identify the cause of a test failure.

Your example makes it obvious which assertion has failed.  Consider that as your build up tests, this will not necessarily be the case.  With a single assertion per test you can identify the cause by the test name.  If you were to validate using some other means than assert, having your test continue upon failure - it will be much less obvious which condition failed without analyzing the log.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to abuse the assert for the "diff/debug-infos", you can catch the `AssertionError`.  E.g.:

```
def a = 42
def b = 666

try {
    assert a==b
}
catch (AssertionError e) {
    println e.message
}
print "the end"

// assert a==b
//        || |
//        || 666
//        |false
//        42
// the end
```